# Рекурсия. Сколько существует таких чисел и, что 1 < и < 500 и А(и) = 8?

Tags: python

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
def F(n):
    if n == 0:
        return F(0)
    if n > 0 and n % 2:
        return F(n/2)
    if n % 2 != 0:
        return 1+F(n-1)
count = 0
for i in range(-1000,1000):
    if (F(i) >= 1) and (F(i) <= 500) and (F(i) == 8):
        print(F(i))
```

Не очень понимаю, почему этот код не работает для этого задания

Comment: % даёт остаток от деления. Вы наоборот сделали для нечетных чисел условие n > 0 and n % 2 .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы не верно написали условия.

```
def F(n):
    if n == 0:
        return 0
    elif n > 0 and not (n % 2):
        return F(n/2)
    elif n % 2 :
        return 1+F(n-1)
    else:
        raise ValueError(f'Не предусмотренное условиями задачи n = {n}')
```

Comment: Действительно, я дурак, не вижу ошибку прямо перед собой, спасибо вам большое)

Answer (score 1):

а почему соственно

```
for i in range(-1000,1000):
```

если

```
for i in range(0,501):
```

и самое главное. Зачем проверять 1<=F(i)<=500? Вместо

```
if (F(i) >= 1) and (F(i) <= 500) and (F(i) == 8):
```

должно быть

```
if F(i) == 8:
```

И напоследок к рекурсии

```
def F(n):
    if n == 0:
        return 0 # В вашем варианте return F(0) - бесконечная рекурсия
    if n % 2 == 0: # зачем проверять отрицательные числа?
        return F(n/2)
    if n % 2 != 0:
        return 1+F(n-1)
```

Comment: Да, вы правы. Но даже так у меня сыпет ошибку:" File 
    if F(i) == 8:
  File "C:\Users\yura\PycharmProjects\programmfor5\main.py", line 3, in F
    return F(0)
  File "C:\Users\yura\PycharmProjects\programmfor5\main.py", line 3, in F
    return F(0)
  File "C:\Users\yura\PycharmProjects\programmfor5\main.py", line 3, in F
    return F(0)
  [Previous line repeated 995 more times]
  File "C:\Users\yura\PycharmProjects\programmfor5\main.py", line 2, in F
    if n == 0:
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison

Answer (score 1):

Кроме неправильного условия для четности, вот эта часть

```
def F(n):
    if n == 0:
        return F(0)
```

никогда не закончится. Вернее, закончится ошибкой превышения глубины рекурсии, потому что все время будет вызываться F(0). Замените `return F(0)` на `return 0`.